# Comment peut-on faire pour dormir sur les deux oreilles ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison

Lorsque l'on veut souhaiter une bonne nuit (profonde et en toute sécurité) à quelqu'un on lui souhaite de dormir sur ses deux oreilles. Mais qu'elle est l'origine de cette expression ?

Comment: Les livres n'en donnent pas plus qu'[Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/dormir-sur-ses-deux-oreilles.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'origine franchement établie.

*[Ces remarques](http://www.pourquois.com/expressions_langage/pourquoi-dormir-deux-oreilles.html)*  correspondent à ce que l'on comprend intuitivement.

Personnellement je l'entends comme "Dormir *avec* ses deux oreilles *fermées*", c'est-à-dire être dans un lieu calme et sécurisé où l'on peut se boucher les oreilles et s'abandonner à un sommeil récupérateur.